# Hive Compaction process

Tags: hive, bigdata

Can anyone help by depicting the compaction process in Hive please? I am new to this and was trying compaction on delta files but it always shows "initiated" and never complete.

This is happening for both Major and Minor compaction. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?